# How do I use a drop-down list in D3 to subset a dataset for drawing line charts?

Tags: drop-down-menu, svg, d3.js, parameter-passing, subset

I'm trying to use a drop-down list that allows a user to select a category, and then the D3 svg will chart several lines associated with that category by subsetting a master list based on the selected item.  I originally had an unordered list with pretty squares, and when a user clicked anywhere on a line, the chart would be updated with the selected category:

```
function select_category(data_key) {
  "use strict";
  var key_items = d3.select('.d3_curve-key')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data_key)
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'd3_curve-key_line')
    .attr('id', function(d) {return d.category_id + "_key";} )
    ;
  key_items.append('div')
    .attr('id', function(d) {
      return 'd3_curve-key_square_' + d.category_id;
      })
    .attr('class', function(d) {
      return 'd3_curve-key_square ' + d.category_id;
      })
    ;
  key_items.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'd3_curve-key_label')
    .text( function(d) {return d.category_name;} )
    ;
  d3.selectAll('.d3_curve-key_line')
    .on('click', get_category_data)
    ;
}

function get_category_data(data_key,i){
  var selected_id = data_key.category_id;
  var ts = d3.select('#'+selected_id);
  d3.json(
    "/category_details.json",
    function(data) {
      filtered_data = data.filter( function(d) {
        return d.category_id === selected_id;})
        ;
      draw_percentiles(filtered_data, selected_id);
      }
    );
}

function draw_percentiles(line_data, line_id){
  // SVG commands.
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Now I'm trying to use the drop-down and pass on the same data and subset parameters, but for some reason the parameter for the selected category (and the dataset for that matter) are not being passed on to the drawing function:

```
var selection_drop_down = d3.select('#d3_curve-selection_area')
  .append('select')
    .on('change', get_category_data)
  .selectAll('option')
  .data(data_key)
  .enter()
  .append('option')
    .attr('class', 'd3_curve-selection_area-drop_down_list')
    .attr('id', function(d) {return d.category_id + "_key";} )
    .attr('value', function(d) {return d.category_id;} )
    .text( function(d) {return d.category_name;} ) 
  ;
```

The drop-down list is being presented correctly, but nothing is being passed to the get_category_data function.

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure what version of the D3 library you're using. Your d3.json callback signature is of the D3 v2 type. If you are using D3 v3, you will need to change it: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Upgrading-to-3.0

Comment: I'm using v2 for the moment.  But thanks for the heads up on the new version!

Answer (score 0):

Your function get_category_data is being called without any arguments passed to it.

Since it doesn't look like get_category_data uses the index variable from here, you could probably get away with changing

```
var selected_id = data_key.category_id;
```

to

```
var selected_id = this.category_id;
```

and changing the definition of your function from

```
function get_category_data(data_key,i){
```

to

```
function get_category_data(){
```

This answer might also be helpful:
[Adding drop down menu using d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903709/adding-drop-down-menu-using-d3-js)