# d3j: Change variables to plot

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to plot a csv file using d3j. I can get a simple scatter plot up and running with no problem. This is what I am having trouble with:

Assume that the columns are x,y,z. I want the user to be able to plot any combination (x vs y, x vs z, y vs z, and so on)  (just like the http://www.gapminder.org/world/ where you can select the axis amongst many variables).

Could any one point me to an example where I can learn this?

Thanks

Comment: @meetamit : Could you please update the link. The example link is this same post. Thanks.

Comment: Here's [an example](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/3201160) and here's a [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611541/return-data-based-on-dropdown-menu) on the same topic.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the link to the example.