# D3.js: get value of selected option?

Tags: d3.js

I want to get the value of the selected option from a dropdown list, in D3.js.

```
<select>
<option data-graph="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903709/adding-drop-down-menu-using-d3-js) which explains how to get the value when the select changes:

```
d3.select("#myselect").on("change", change)
function change() {
    this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
}
```

But how can I get the selected value on page load, not when the select is changed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to use D3 to do that:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('myselect');
console.log(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value)
```

Comment: Oh yes... I guess I don't actually need D3 to do that :)

Comment: if you want to use d3: var sel = d3.select('#myselect').node()

Comment: Actually I have to change `#myselect` to just `select` in the above, for it to work.

Comment: @Richard  Can't believe none of the highly voted answers below works for me in IE but your comment above worked for me! I have a a feeling it's an IE issue...

Answer (score 53):

I found this to be the simplest:

```
d3.select("#objectID").node().value;
```

Which is the text of the selected option in the following node: `<select id="objectID"></select>`

Note that `d3.node()` is documented at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#node and the `.value` property of an `HTMLInputElement` is documented on MDN at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement.

Answer (score 33):

Use the [`.property()` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#property):

```
d3.select("#objectID").property("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen

```
d3.select("#objectID")[0][0].value
```

But I'm quite sure this is generally a bad idea...

Comment: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections  -  "However, you can still loop over elements manually if you wish: there's an each operator which invokes an arbitrary function, and selections are arrays, so elements can be accessed directly (e.g., selection[0][0])" - It seems this access method is mainly intended for looping, and, in my not-very-experienced opinion, is slightly less clear than the other answers.